# Email with lots of links fails

Tags: email, indy, email-spam

I am trying to send an email using an Indy Email Client.  The body of the email is pretty much a list of various websites (like 50 to 100).  The email server is Yahoo.  I am finding the email is not going through (I get a "Connection Closed Gracefully" exception).  But if I change all instances of "**/**" to different letters the email goes through.  Example:

Change **http://mysite.com/mypage.html** to **http:XXmysite.comXmypage.html**

Could the email server be rejecting the email because it looks like spam?

Comment: I think only the Yahoo mail team can answer for sure.

Comment: Either Yahoo, or a local anti-virus/anti-malware program instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Goadddy was denying them because links contained in the email were noted as spam sites.